# PHP HOURLY RATE CALCULATOR

Tags: php

Person a has an hourly rate of 9.500 (Yes three decimal places in our country)

He has worked for 8 hours and 15 minutes and 0 seconds which is in the format 08:15:00.

Im getting the variables as below

```
$iCostPerHour = '9.500';
$timespent = '08.15'; //i got this by converting from 08:15:00
```

How do i calculate the cost for this time?

Currently what i did is

```
echo number_format(($timespent * $iCostPerHour), 3, '.', ',')
```

And it is returing a wrong value.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What ? why downvote?

Comment: What have you done to try solving this problem yourself?

Comment: @miken32 I've updated the question.

Comment: 8:15 is the same as 8.25 hours numerically. 15 minutes is one quarter of an hour, not 15 percent. @Ditto

Comment: @Qirel You are correct

Comment: Why would you expect `$timespent * $iCostPerHour` to work when `$timespent` is clearly a string?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, but i've changed the string from 8:15:00 to 8.15

Comment: @miken32 You are wrong it is not a duplicate of that question. This is about PHP HOURLY RATE CALCULATOR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$iCostPerHour = 9.500;
$timespent = '08:15:00';
$timeparts=explode(':',$timespent);
$pay=$timeparts[0]*$iCostPerHour+$timeparts[1]/60*$iCostPerHour;
echo $pay;
```

Live demo https://eval.in/740789

Comment: @Alexy Shatrov You are the man. But how does it calculate 0 hous & 30 Mins

Comment: If you mean - $timespent = '00:15:00' - it will be calculated.